# Node Js Is not recognized by Jenkins ver. 2.138.3

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, appium

I am trying to execute Appium cucumber test using maven and in my jenkins server. I am getting this error. I have already installed NodeJS+Plugin  and restarted the server. Still, my Jenkins job throws me this error. Here is the error log and versions I am using, Glad if someone can help to resolve this.

updated 1 package in 5.097s
npm  6.4.1
node    v10.15.3
appium  v1.9.1
java    "1.8.0_201"

```
io.appium.java_client.service.local.InvalidServerInstanceException: Invalid server instance exception has occured: There is no installed nodes! Please install node via NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/package/appium#using-node-js) or download and install Appium app (http://appium.io/downloads.html)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.findNodeInCurrentFileSystem(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:155)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.checkAppiumJS(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:309)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServiceBuilder.createArgs(AppiumServiceBuilder.java:389)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:332)
    at io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(AppiumDriverLocalService.java:76)
    at utils.AppiumServerUtils.<init>(AppiumServerUtils.java:18)
    at appium.BaseTest.launchAppiumServer(BaseTest.java:136)
    at steps.common.CommonSteps.beforeScenario(CommonSteps.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:202)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
    at utils.CustomRunner.run(CustomRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
    at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.start(JUnit4TestRunner.java:81)
    at org.testng.junit.JUnit4TestRunner.run(JUnit4TestRunner.java:69)
    at org.testng.TestRunner$1.run(TestRunner.java:689)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1014)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRunJUnit(TestRunner.java:720)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeSingleClass(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:112)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:99)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: /tmp/get_path_to_default_node5935932351970587419.sh: line 2: npm: command not found
```

Comment: anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be telling you that you do not have Node installed on the Jenkins Slave you're attempting to run the tests on. Although you may have the NodeJS plugin installed in Jenkins, you will need configure the job with the node version you want to use.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin

Comment: where can we configure that?

Comment: As the plugin page describes, it's configured in the job.

Comment: I have already configured it in the job but still getting the same issue any idea?